# Получение объекта класса из стека

Tags: c++, классы, объекты, стек

Суть проблемы вот в чем, мне нужно передать в стек объект класса, а затем вынуть его оттуда, но после того как я вынимаю его и передаю из стека обратно в объект, то поля класса не заполняются значениями объекта который был передан в стек.  Как это возможно реализовать?

## Вот код

```
#include "Pharmacy.h"//мой класс
#include "Hospital.h"//мой класс 
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<Pharmacy> stkPharmObj; //стак объектов класса

    string str;
    Pharmacy objPharmacy, objPharmacy1, objPharmacy2, objPharmacy3;


//Внизу куча текста, для запроса и передачи значений. Знаю, делал через цикл, тоже не работало, но так я хоть уверен, что все ввел. Сорян за количество строк
    cout << "Input Town" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        cin.ignore();
        objPharmacy.setTown(str);


        cout << "Input name" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy.setName(str);


        cout << "Input Street" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy.setStreet(str);


        cout << "Input NumberBuilding" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy.setNumberBuilding(str);

        stkPharmObj.push(objPharmacy);//Вот первый объект в стек


        cout << "Input Town" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        cin.ignore();
        objPharmacy1.setTown(str);


        cout << "Input name" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy1.setName(str);


        cout << "Input Street" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy1.setStreet(str);


        cout << "Input NumberBuilding" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy1.setNumberBuilding(str);

        stkPharmObj.push(objPharmacy1);//Вот второй


        cout << "Input Town" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        cin.ignore();
        objPharmacy2.setTown(str);


        cout << "Input name" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy2.setName(str);


        cout << "Input Street" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy2.setStreet(str);


        cout << "Input NumberBuilding" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy2.setNumberBuilding(str);

        stkPharmObj.push(objPharmacy2);//Вот третий


        cout << "Input Town" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        cin.ignore();
        objPharmacy3.setTown(str);


        cout << "Input name" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy3.setName(str);


        cout << "Input Street" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy3.setStreet(str);


        cout << "Input NumberBuilding" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        objPharmacy3.setNumberBuilding(str);

        stkPharmObj.push(objPharmacy3);//Вот четвертый



    objPharmacy = stkPharmObj.top();//вот тут я пытаюсь объекту передать значение последнего объекта, должен в этом отображаться объект 3

//функции отображения.
    objPharmacy.Show();//здэс пустота, поля не пришли из объекта который я пытался достато из стека

    objPharmacy2.Show();//а здесь все отлична

//Хотя стек принял все объекты норм и указал размер 4

    system("pause");
}
```

## Ниже код класса

```
    #pragma once
    #include "BasikZaklad.h"
    class Pharmacy :    public BasikZaklad
    {
    private:

        string strWorkingKlas, strFormVlas;

    public:
        Pharmacy() {};
        Pharmacy(const Pharmacy &obj) 
        {
            setWorkingKlas(strWorkingKlas);
            setFormVlas(strFormVlas);
        };
        ~Pharmacy() {};

        virtual void Show() override
        {
            cout << "string strWorkingKlas ==" << getWorkingKlas() << endl;
            cout << "string strFormVlas ==" << getFormVlas() << endl;   

            BasikZaklad::Show();
        }

        void setWorkingKlas(string strWorkingKlas);
        void setFormVlas(string strFormVlas);

        string getWorkingKlas(void) { return strWorkingKlas; }
        string getFormVlas(void) { return strFormVlas; }
    };

    void Pharmacy::setWorkingKlas(string strWorkingKlas)
    {
        try
        {
            char* chWorkingKlas{};
            int iCountWorkingKlas = 0;

            if ((chWorkingKlas = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char))) == 0)
            {
                printf("\nMemory allocation failure\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                chWorkingKlas[i] = strWorkingKlas[i];
                if (checkNumbers(strWorkingKlas)) throw chWorkingKlas;
                if (strWorkingKlas[i] == '\0') break;

                iCountWorkingKlas++;
                if (iCountWorkingKlas > 40) throw iCountWorkingKlas;
            }

            if (!islower(strWorkingKlas[0]))
            {

                this->strWorkingKlas = strWorkingKlas;
            }
            else throw strWorkingKlas;

        }
        catch (char* chWorkingKlas)
        {
            cout << "Error invalid WorkingKlas!!! Wright it without numbers or other chars" << endl;
        }

        catch (string strWorkingKlas)
        {
            cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Wright it from big letter" << endl;
        }
        catch (int iCountWorkingKlas)
        {
            cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Too much chars" << endl;
        }

    }


    void Pharmacy::setFormVlas(string strFormVlas)
    {
        try
        {
            char* chFormVlas{};
            int iCountFormVlas = 0;

            if ((chFormVlas = (char*)calloc(60, sizeof(char))) == 0)
            {
                printf("\nMemory allocation failure\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                chFormVlas[i] = strFormVlas[i];
                if (checkNumbers(strFormVlas)) throw chFormVlas;
                if (strFormVlas[i] == '\0') break;

                iCountFormVlas++;
                if (iCountFormVlas > 60) throw iCountFormVlas;
            }

            if (!islower(strFormVlas[0]))
            {

                this->strFormVlas = strFormVlas;
            }
            else throw strFormVlas;

        }
        catch (char* chFormVlas)
        {
            cout << "Error invalid WorkingKlas!!! Wright it without numbers or other chars" << endl;
        }

        catch (string strFormVlas)
        {
            cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Wright it from big letter" << endl;
        }
        catch (int iCountFormVlas)
        {
            cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Too much chars" << endl;
        }

    }
```

## Код Родительского класса

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BasikZaklad
{
private:
    string strName, strTown, strStreet, strNumberBuilding;

public:
    BasikZaklad() {};
    BasikZaklad(const BasikZaklad &obj)
    {
        setName(strName);
        setTown(strTown);
        setStreet(strStreet);
        setNumberBuilding(strNumberBuilding);
    }
    ~BasikZaklad() {};


    virtual void Show()
    {       
        cout << "string strName ==" << getName() << endl;
        cout << "string strTown ==" << getTown() << endl;
        cout << "string strStreet ==" << getStreet() << endl;
        cout << "string strNumberBuilding ==" << getNumberBuilding() << endl;
    }

    bool checkNumbers(string strSome); //функция для проверки на номера
    bool checkNumbersAdress(string strSome1); //функция для проверки Adress

    //зміна полів класу 
    void setName(string strName);
    void setTown(string strTown);
    void setStreet(string strStreet);
    void setNumberBuilding(string strNumberBuilding);


    //Зчитування полів  
    string getName(void) { return strName; }
    string getTown(void) { return strTown; }
    string getStreet(void) { return strStreet; }
    string getNumberBuilding(void) { return strNumberBuilding; }

};
bool BasikZaklad::checkNumbers(string strSome)
{
    char chNumbers[32] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9', '/', ';','<', '>', ',', '.', '?', ']', '[', '{', '}', '!', '@', '#', '%', '^', '&', '(', ')', '_', '+', '=' };

    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        {
            if (strSome[i] == chNumbers[j]) { return true; }
        }

        if (strSome[i] == '\0') break;
    }
    return false;
}


bool BasikZaklad::checkNumbersAdress(string strSome1)
{
    char chNumbers[21] = {  ';','<', '>', ',', '.', '?', ']', '[', '{', '}', '!', '@', '#', '%', '^', '&', '(', ')', '_', '+', '=' };

    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
        {
            if (strSome1[i] == chNumbers[j]) { return true; }
        }

        if (strSome1[i] == '\0') break;
    }
    return false;
}


void BasikZaklad::setName(string strName)
{
    try
    {
        char* chName{};
        int iCountName = 0;

        if ((chName = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char))) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nMemory allocation failure\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            chName[i] = strName[i];
            if (checkNumbersAdress(strName)) throw chName;
            if (strName[i] == '\0') break;

            iCountName++;
            if (iCountName > 40) throw iCountName;
        }

        if (!islower(strName[0]))
        {

            this->strName = strName;
        }
        else throw strName;

    }
    catch (char* chName)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Name!!! Wright it without numbers or other chars" << endl;
    }

    catch (string strName)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Name!!! Wright it from big letter" << endl;
    }
    catch (int iCountName)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Name!!! Too much chars" << endl;
    }

}


void BasikZaklad::setTown(string strTown)
{
    try
    {
        char* chTown{};
        int iCountTown = 0;

        if ((chTown = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char))) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nMemory allocation failure\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            chTown[i] = strTown[i];
            if (checkNumbers(strTown)) throw chTown;
            if (strTown[i] == '\0') break;

            iCountTown++;
            if (iCountTown > 40) throw iCountTown;
        }

        if (!islower(strTown[0]))
        {

            this->strTown = strTown;
        }
        else throw strTown;

    }
    catch (char* chTown)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Wright it without numbers or other chars" << endl;
    }

    catch (string strTown)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Wright it from big letter" << endl;
    }
    catch (int iCountTown)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Town!!! Too much chars" << endl;
    }

}


void BasikZaklad::setStreet(string strStreet)
{
    try
    {
        char* chStreet{};
        int iCountStreet = 0;

        if ((chStreet = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char))) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nMemory allocation failure\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            chStreet[i] = strStreet[i];
            if (checkNumbers(strStreet)) throw chStreet;
            if (strStreet[i] == '\0') break;

            iCountStreet++;
            if (iCountStreet > 40) throw iCountStreet;
        }

        if (!islower(strStreet[0]))
        {

            this->strStreet = strStreet;
        }
        else throw strStreet;

    }
    catch (char* chStreet)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Street!!! Wright it without numbers or other chars" << endl;
    }

    catch (string strStreet)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Street!!! Wright it from big letter" << endl;
    }
    catch (int iCountStreet)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid Street!!! Too much chars" << endl;
    }

}


void BasikZaklad::setNumberBuilding(string strNumberBuilding)
{
    try
    {
        char* chNumberBuilding{};
        int iCountNumberBuilding = 0;

        if ((chNumberBuilding = (char*)calloc(10, sizeof(char))) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nMemory allocation failure\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            chNumberBuilding[i] = strNumberBuilding[i];
            if (checkNumbersAdress(strNumberBuilding)) throw chNumberBuilding;
            if (strNumberBuilding[i] == '\0') break;

            iCountNumberBuilding++;
            if (iCountNumberBuilding > 10) throw iCountNumberBuilding;
        }

            this->strNumberBuilding = strNumberBuilding;


    }
    catch (char* chNumberBuilding)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid NumberBuilding!!! Wright it without other chars" << endl;
    }


    catch (int iCountNumberBuilding)
    {
        cout << "Error invalid NumberBuilding!!! Too much chars" << endl;
    }

}
```

Следил в Вижуалке за наполнение, все объекты в стеке пусты.

Comment: А как **вы** это делаете?

Comment: А есть ли у `Pharmacy` конструктор копирования? Вообще реализацию класса тоже следует привести чтобы получился [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторах копирования поля копируемого объекта не используются, вместо них используются пустые поля этого объекта. Копирование базого класса вообще не происходит. Должно быть:

```
Pharmacy(const Pharmacy &obj) 
:    BasikZaklad{obj}
,    strWorkingKlas{obj.strWorkingKlas}
,    strFormVlas{obj.strFormVlas}
{}
```

На самом деле реализовывать конструктор копирования вручную в данном случае не целесообразно, можно отдать это на откуп копилятору:

```
Pharmacy(const Pharmacy &obj) = default;
```

Следует всегда читать (и устранять причины) предупреждений компилятора. В данном случае он наверняка жаловался на неиспользуемый аргумент `obj`.

Comment: Нет, он не жаловался на  аргументы, кроме тех, что в блоках     catch, только они неиспользуемые.

Comment: @Vereh Возможно у вас предупреждения  отключены.

Comment: Все предупреждения включены, я за ними стараюсь следить

Comment: @Vereh А что за компилятор? Неиспользуемый аргумент функции при всех включенных предупреждениях должен вызывать предупреждение в g++, clang++  и vc++.

Comment: У меня Microsoft Visual Studio 17 года

Comment: @В студии должно было выскочить `warning C4100`. Проверьте, что Warning level стоит W4. Еще в студии можно включить статический анализ и проверки Core Guidelines.

Comment: Да есть,     warning C4101. Но там только переменные из блоков catch в классах, я по всем прошелся.

Comment: @Vereh [пример в онлайн компиляторе](https://godbolt.org/g/HKMTLT)

Comment: Да, все уже. Спасибо огромное! Я последовал совету и отдал компилятору конструктор копирования, теперь все работает)